# Asus anti-surge protection fried (?) motherboard and PSU

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, surge-protection

I bought a PC about two months ago, and it was working great until yesterday. I was playing *[Magicka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magicka)* (a [Steam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_(software)) game) which is a very light game and suddenly my PC rebooted. When it came back, the initial screen had the text "Asus anti-surge was triggered to protect system from unstable power supply" (or something like that). Then just after that screen disappeared it shutdown and never came back!! It has absolutely no sign of life; I tried to change the PSU and had no success. Anyone have any idea?

I also tried to test my PSU in my brother's computer. The CPU fan shows a small sign of life (it rotates once), but it stops right after. I also tested a normally functioning PSU on my computer with no success either.

I'm afraid that I fried my PSU and my motherboard!

Here`s my configuration:

- PSU: Corsair CX750
- Motherboard: Asus H87M-E
- CPU: Intel i7 4770 Haskell
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce 770GTX
- RAM: 16 GB kingston DDR3 1600
- HD: Seagate 1 TB SATA3

Updates from another forum:

- Motherboard LED and Ethernet LED are both working fine.
- Paperclip test on PSU successful. It works.
- Tested PSU in my brother's computer. It doesn't work.
- Actually the CPU cooler rotates ONCE and stops. So it shows a small signal of life.
- Tested my brother's PSU in my computer. It didnt't work.
- GPU tested and it is working fine.
- I didn't test memories nor CPU.

What should I do?

Comment: Guys, I was reading this manual about my MB:
[link](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/H87M-E/E8197_H87M-E.pdf)
And I saw this part:
Asus DRAM fuse.
    - Enhanced DRAM overcurrent protection and short circuit damage prevention.
Maybe it's just a fried fuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the PSU took the hit and got fried. If you have a voltmeter or know someone with one, or just buy one at RadioShack ([Voltmeter](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=4214667)), test the output voltage of the PSU and make sure that it matches the manual. Here is brief video [explaining the process testing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Or7_Za_dYBE)

Comment: Thank you for your response Sauce!
Well, I'll test it in a few hours.
If the PSU is ok, is there anyway I can find out what's wrong with the MB?

Comment: Hey Sauce, I tested the PSU with the Volt Meter and everything was working just fine except for one little thing. The 24pin cable ( big one ) which connects to the MB has all its voltage fine except for the blue wire. It's showing -35v. I looked in the internet and it seems that -12v is expected. Do you think this is a problem?

Comment: that is very large difference. typical difference should be no more than few decimal points. There should be nothing going to motherboard more than +12v or -12v. I can't say for sure but it is possible that you motherboard might be fried too because of high voltage from power supply. I had power supply that fried 3 different motherboards before I figured that it was causing issues.

Comment: I'm almost sure that my mobo has been fried AND I must buy a new PSU.
Do you know how can I be sure that my mobo is fried?

Comment: Once you buy new PSU just plug it in and see what happens, it is possible that MB is still fine.